# How to compare strings and integers defined by #define?

Tags: c++, arduino, c-preprocessor

I have the following C++ code:

```cpp
#define VERSION        1
#define TYPE           "this"
...

bool update(const char* json) {
    ...
    const char* theType = doc["type"];     // "this"
    int theVer          = doc["version"];  // 2

    //int ourVer        = VERSION;
    //char ourType[]    = TYPE;

    if ( (theVer > VERSION) && (theType == TYPE) ) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can print both `theType` and `theVer`, but I am not able to successfully compare them with the constants. I also tried to compare to the *casted* constants (commented out) to no avail.

**How do I compare strings and integers defined by #define?**

BTW. This is coded in ArduinoIDE.

Comment: `theType == TYPE` compares the pointers, not content.  Use `strcmp` instead.

Comment: @L.F. The comments section is for comments, not answers. Use the answer section instead.

Comment: How do you arrange for `doc[std::string]` to return two different types depending on the run-time value of the string?

Comment: Also: `if (some complicated expression) { return true; } else { return false; }` can be written much more simply (and, imo idiomatically) as `return some_complicated_expression;`

Comment: @rici Obviously I will do something else there, and just trying to simplify the code to be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`theType == TYPE` compares two pointers.  It returns true if and only if the addresses are the same, which is not the case here.

Use [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) instead:

```
if (theVer > VERSION && std::strcmp(theType, TYPE) == 0) {
    // ...
}
```

`strcmp` three-way compares the actual strings, returning a number that is `< 0`, `== 0`, or `> 0` when the first string is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.  You need `#include <cstring>` for this.

Answer (score 2):

I know L.F's answer has already been accepted but i wish to dissent on their advice to use `strcmp`.  you shouldn't even be using `#define` anymore but `constexpr` instead. This allows you to be clear on typing and, in my experience, `constexpr` play's nicer with intellisense.

What you should use for `TYPE` is `constexpr std::string_view`. which wont force you to use old c libraries and can be compared with `std::string` using the == operator.

```
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

constexpr int THIS = 1;
constexpr std::string_view TYPE = "this";
...

bool update(const std::string & json) {
    ...
    std::string theType = doc["type"]; // "this"
    int theVer = doc["version"];  // 2

    if ( (theVer > VERSION) && (theType == TYPE) ) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view

Comment: Hi @qctdev and welcome to SO. Your solution is helpful and interesting, since I have not used this syntax before, so please provide a link to the docs. In addition, I am using `#define` because it is doing many other things in my code, that will never change and sometimes not needed for other compiles.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added the documentation links. You know your own code best so i shall devolve to your judgement on how it should work. I just wished to state what i understand to be the 'proper' way of doing things should anyone else happen along.

Comment: Question is if `std::string_view` is available in Arduino. This is light platform (2kB of RAM) so there is no heap, so many stuff can't be used there. Bottom line I wouldn't be surprised if there is no `std::string_view` for Arduino (didn't verified that), on other hand since it doesn't use heap there might be some limited version of it (possibly under different name).

Comment: to my knowledge string_view doesn't require a heap be available(it works just dandy with things on the stack), however I've just checked and c++ 17 doesn't appear to available for Arduino. Without support for the 2017 standard you wont be able to use string_view (unless you re-implement it yourself which which would be a lot of work for little gain).

Comment: There are third-party implementations of `string_view`, if you want to use them without C++17. You're absolutely right that it doesn't require any storage allocation; that's its entire point. It's very lightweight, and there's absolutely no reason not to use it on an embedded platform. (Indeed, it can often reduce memory use.)

Comment: Using all UPPERCASE names for compile time constant is antipattern.

Comment: All caps constants, compile time or otherwise, seems to be the default everywhere I've looked.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` is irrelevant.

After preprocessing, your snippet is exactly equivalent to:

```
bool update(const char* json) {
    const char* theType = doc["type"];     // "this"
    int theVer          = doc["version"];  // 2

    if ( (theVer > 1) && (theType == "this") ) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So the problem is reduced to "how do we compare two C-strings?", with a much simpler example like this:

```
int main()
{
   const char* theType = "this";
   const bool  matches = (theType == "this");
}
```

The answer is, [not with `==`, but with `strcmp`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8004237/560648).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define VERSION        1
#define TYPE           "this"
...

bool update(const char* json) {
   ...
   const char* theType = doc["type"];     // "this"
   int theVer          = doc["version"];  // 2

   return (theVer > VERSION) && !strcmp(TYPE,theType) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help you:

```
bool func()
{
    const string str = "value";
    int number = 3;
    return str == const_string && number == const_number ? true : false;
}
```